# Bootstrap v4 ".form-row" not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, twitter-bootstrap-4

Why is `.form-row` in Bootstrap v4 not working? I can use `.row` but not `.form-row`.

I want to align form inputs vertically as described in the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an outdated (alpha) version of Bootstrap. Update to the 4.0 release and you can use `.form-row`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/